# PHP function fsockopen never returning false

Tags: php, fsockopen

Could somebody help me with the php function fsockopen?

if I call the function like this :

```
$fp = fsockopen('xywqnda.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 10);
```

With an unavailable host domain, it will never return false and I don't understand why!

Comment: Strange, when I run that code, I get `$fp` equal to `bool(false)`.

Comment: here is my code:
    <?
     error_reporting(E_ALL);
     ini_set("display_errors","on");

     $fp = fsockopen("udp://2.2.2.2", 13, $errno, $errstr);
     if (!$fp)
      echo "offline\n";
     else 
      echo "online\n";
    ?>

Comment: Please update your original question, this is much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, you are using UDP.  Your original example didn't show this.  This changes things.  From the PHP manual:

> **Warning**
>
> UDP sockets will sometimes appear to have opened without an error, even if the remote host is unreachable. The error will only
>   become apparent when you read or write data to/from the socket. The
>   reason for this is because UDP is a "connectionless" protocol, which
>   means that the operating system does not try to establish a link for
>   the socket until it actually needs to send or receive data.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ini_set("display_errors","on")
```

it will show up a warning if the domain is invalid, other than that the function will return TRUE because the file pointer is returned, meaning file was created with success, FALSE will be returned only if it can't create the file.

Comment: I already tried something like this, it was error_reporting(E_ERROR), and both are not working...Thank's anyway for your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
// displays all warnings, notices and errors
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$fp = fsockopen('xywqnda.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 10);
```

The connection attempt will timeout after 10 seconds.
You will get a warning because the domain is unavailable.
$errno and $errstr will contain the system error number and error message.
The function will return false, so $fp will be equal to false.

Documentation: [fsockopen](http://php.net/fsockopen)

Comment: here is my code:
    <?
     error_reporting(E_ALL);
     ini_set("display_errors","on");

     $fp = fsockopen("udp://2.2.2.2", 13, $errno, $errstr);
     if (!$fp)
      echo "offline\n";
     else 
      echo "online\n";
    ?>